# Unknown type error for typedefed structure

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm trying to make a linked list for a bookshelf, but when I compile it says

```
In file included from libreria.c:3:0:
libreria.h:8:2: error: unknown type name ‘Book’
  Book* next;
  ^
```

Like if Book is not defined.
this is the header file

```
#ifndef LIBRERIA_H
#define LIBRERIA_H

typedef struct Book {
    char author[50];
    char title[50];
    int year;
    Book* next;
} Book;

void newbook(Book* book);

#endif
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Use `struct Book* next;` instead of `Book* next;`

Comment: You can't use a `typedef`'d name, inside of the type definition you're typedef-ing. C isn't inception, so just write the name in full: `struct Book *next;` or move the `typedef` [see this example](https://eval.in/426149). But that sort of opaque typedefs shouldn't be recommended unless you're writing an API of sorts (like `FILE *`), or a shared library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of your struct definition, the typedef for `Book` hasn't been defined yet, so you need to use `struct Book` in that instance:

```
typedef struct Book {
    char author[50];
    char title[50];
    int year;
    struct Book* next;
} Book;
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside the structure definition, `Book` is not a type *yet*. You need to use `struct Book` as the type instead.

Otherwise, you can put the `typedef` beforehands the structure definition to make `Book` itself act as type, like

```
typedef struct Book Book;
struct Book {
char author[50];
char title[50];
int year;
Book* next;
}
```